# How to set uneditable input text box to editable using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm using firebug and in a page there is one text field:

```
 <INPUT TYPE="PASSWORD" NAME="CorporateSignonPassword" size="20" maxlength="28" >
```

and this field is disabled. Actually I've forgotten password in my banking login account and it is forcing me to type in my long passwords using visual keybord buttons.

Why isn't this working?:

```
$("input").attr("editable",true);
```

or

```
  $("input").attr("disabled",false);
```

I've jquerified the page.

Comment: what are you trying to do again?

Comment: I want to type in my passwords in the password field rather than clicking visual randomized keyboard buttons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using >= jQuery 1.6 then you should be using the prop() method rather than attr() in this particular instance:

```
$("input").prop("disabled", true);
```

or

```
$("input").prop("disabled", false);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about removing the "readonly" attribute? I think input tag has an attribute called "readonly".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("input[type='password']").attr('disabled', false);
```